# Cambiar columnas de str a float leyendo desde un csv

Tags: python, pandas, csv, float

Tengo un archivo csv (adjunto foto) que contiene varias columnas.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Necesito que se pase este simple archivo a un xlsx con las condiciones de:

- Algunas de las columnas me interesa que se queden como string y otras que quiero que las lea como float. Las columnas ''num1'' ''num2'' y ''num3'' quiero que las convierta en float ya que contienen numeros con decimales.
- Las demás columnas me interesa que estén como string

La línea de leer el csv con la separación ';' y el engine:'python' no creo que sea problema ya que en otros archivos que tengo que leer lo necesito. En este caso lo que me interesa es que cree un dataframe a partir del csv que leo, y que reconozca las columnas que me interesan como floats para poder realizar operaciones con esas celdas. No lo he llegado a conseguir, ya que he utilizado algun comando como astype o dtype me pone que es imposible convertir los string (celdas numéricas del csv) a float.

Ajunto el código que he realizado de lectura y salida:

```
import pandas as pd

# convertir archivo .csv a .xlsx

df = pd.read_csv('file1.csv', sep=';', engine='python')
df = df.set_index('nombre')  # incluido por que me interesa
df.to_excel('output.xlsx', 'Sheet1') # solamente para ver como sale
print(df.dtypes) 
dia_hora    object
num1        object
num2        object
num3        object
dtype: object

# leer archivo .xlsx creado anteriormente para hacer operaciones y manejarlo
df = pd.read_excel('output.xlsx') 
df = df.set_index('nombre') # incluido por que me interesa de nuevo
```

Como se puede ver, el tipo que queda es de object.

Al final me tendría que quedar esto (foto de abajo) pero con las celdas de las columnas 'num1' 'num2 y 'num3' coloreadas, que las reconozca como floats. Luego ya finalmente ese dataframe podría trabajar matemáticamente con el o exportarlo si me interesara.

Agradecería ayuda e incluso poder completar el código para que funcione. Muchas gracias por leerme.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para pasar las columnas a `float`, primero hay que hacer un cambio mínimo que es.. cambiar `,` por `.`. Esto sería utilizando `.replace`, y para aplicarlo a toda la columna, podemos `apply`.

Entonces en este paso reemplazamos `,` por `.`, para cada columna.

```
df['num1'] = df['num1'].apply(lambda x: x.replace(',','.'))
df['num2'] = df['num2'].apply(lambda x: x.replace(',','.'))
df['num3'] = df['num3'].apply(lambda x: x.replace(',','.'))
```

El siguiente paso sería convertir cada columna en `float`. Esto se puede hacer fácil utilizando `.astype()`. Entonces:

```
df['num1'] = df['num1'].astype(float)
df['num2'] = df['num2'].astype(float)
df['num3'] = df['num3'].astype(float)
```

Como verás `astype()`, recibe el tipo de dato deseado y si no hay excepciones que lo impida(por eso cambiamos `,` por `.` ), transformará a ese tipo de dato,en este caso `float`.

Y utilizando la misma estrategia podemos transformar las demás columnas en `string`:

```
df['dia_hora'] = df['dia_hora'].astype(str)
```

Comment: Muchas gracias Lucas. Esto me lo soluciona perfectamente. Siendo algo más refinados... ¿hay alguna otra manera de hacerlo?, por que si hubiera una columna con muchisimos valores a convertir, sería un ''gran'' trabajo de computación.

Answer (score 1):

Tambien puedes hacer:

```
df[['num1','num2','num3']]=df[['num1','num2','num3']].replace(to_replace=',', value='.', regex=True)
df.astype({'num1':float,'num2':float,'num3':float,'dia_hora':str})
```

Comment: Muchas gracias Ronald.